# Hubbard Model Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, lattice-model

Right now I try to understand the Hubbard Model. I do have a question to the Hamiltonian written in this form:

$H=\sum_{m,n}(\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{m+1,n}\hat{c}_{m,n}+\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{m,n+1}\hat{c}_{m,n}+h.c.)$,
where $\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{m,n}$ is the creation operator on site $(m,n)$ and the operator $\hat{c}_{m,n}$ annihilates an electron on site $(m,n)$.

My question is: How does the hermitian conjugate term (h.c.) does exactly look like?

I would be very grateful for answers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Hermitian conjugate of $a_1^\dagger a_2$ is $a_2^\dagger a_1$.

Comment: The Hamiltonian in the OP is actually not the Hubbard Hamiltonian, but a *tight-binding* Hamiltonian, which is diagonalized by wave-like solutions. It is a pretty basic stuff and one can find many tips by searching for *tight binding Hamiltonian* in this community. Hubbard model is obtained by adding the on-site Coulomb interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The Hamiltonian with the hermitian conjugate term writes as follow :
$H=\sum_{m,n}(\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{m+1,n}\hat{c}_{m,n}+\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{m,n+1}\hat{c}_{m,n}+ \hat{c}^{\dagger}_{m,n}\hat{c}_{m+1,n}+\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{m,n}\hat{c}_{m,n+1})$.

Just change the order and add a dagger, you obtain the hermitian conjugate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought about the same, but in general: How does an particle (e.g. an electron)  tunnels around the borders of one lattice unit cell? I think I do not really understand the meaning of this Hamiltonian. Perhaps you can explain it . Thanks in advance.

Comment: In practice, each unit cell of a lattice is located in a local minimum of the potential energy (example : a sine curve from an electromagnetic wave like a laser for example). If the amplitude of the sine (let's call it $V_{0}$) is not infinite, then a particle located in one of those potential minima has a non-zero probability to tunnel to the next local minima. In pratice, atoms have to be cold so that their thermal energy $k_{B}T < V_{0}$ and that this probability remains small enough to consider only next neighbour hopping.